# Return the names of people who have no orders with company X. Result is including someone who has an order with them and another customer

Tags: mysql

I have three tables:

```
t1 - Salesperson
SalesID, Name
1, tom
2, jerry

t2 - Customers
CustID, Name
4, Pod
5, Neo

t3 - Orders
OrderID, CustOrdID, SalesOrdID
999, 1, 4
1000, 1, 5
1001, 2, 5
```

I want to return only the names of the sales persons who have NEVER had an order with Pod (the answer should be just Jerry)

```
select DISTINCT Salesperson.Name
from Salesperson
INNER JOIN Orders on Orders.SalesOrdID=Salesperson.SalesID
INNER JOIN Customers ON Orders.CustOrdID=Customers.CustID
Where Customers.Name <> 'Pod';
```

This is not right because it returns Tom and Jerry as Tom has a sale with Neo in the Orders table.

How can I tell my query to omit any sales person with a sale to POD from my result. I have tried sub queries, IFs, Not exists and I just cannot seem to work out the logic/syntax

Thanks for any help

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Your query selects persons who have ordered something other than Pod. You must obtain all detailed rows from your tables (by joining them all), group them by a person and calculate the amount of ordered Pod, then return only persons who have this amount equal to zero.

Comment: 'it returns Tom and Jerry ' - no it produces nothing , Orders.SalesOrdID=Salesperson.SalesID is never true for the published data

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT Salesperson.Name
FROM Salesperson
INNER JOIN Orders ON Orders.SalesOrdID = Salesperson.SalesID
INNER JOIN Customers ON Orders.CustOrdID = Customers.CustID
GROUP BY Salesperson.Name
HAVING 0 = SUM(Customers.Name = 'Pod')
```